# "Continue" alternative that doesn't skip but repeats the loop

Tags: php, foreach

I'm using PHP's `foreach()`, Sometimes when the inner code doesn't do what i want, I'd like to re-try the same level instead of continuing to the next one.

Is that possible?

Example:

```
foreach($pics AS $pic){
  if(!upload($pic)){
    again; // something like this
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No but you can put a while loop inside your loop, this has equivalent behaviour as what you desire above. However you should modify it to use a counter and stop after X many retries to prevent infinite looping.

```
foreach($pics AS $pic){
  while(!upload($pic));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to surround your `if` with another loop which loops a certain number of times (your maximum retry count), or until you manually `break` out of it when your code succeeds.

You could use a `goto` I suppose, but that is generally frowned upon, and would do the same thing as an inner loop anyway.

Comment: I've never used goto myself, but doesn't that work only to skip forward through code?

Comment: @BradleyForster No idea, to be honest. Just a thought I had from my C background, I'm not sure what the restrictions are in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

```
function dosomething() {
    foreach($pics AS $pic){
        if(!upload($pic)){
            break;
        }
    }
    $success = true;
}

$success=false;
while( !$success ) dosomething();
```

While this in theory should work.
I would say absolutely bad programming practice, as you have a good chance of a never ending loop.